# Можно ли восстановить удалённую ветку в гите, если я уже создал ветку с таким же именем?

Tags: git, контроль-версий, git-branch

Общеизвестно, что удалённую ветку в гите можно восстановить. Моя ситуация осложняется тем, что:

1. Была ветка мастер
2. Я создал ветку NewB. Поработал, сделал много глупостей.
3. Я удалил ветку NewB. Был уверен, что она никогда больше не понадобится.
4. Перешёл в ветку мастер, снова создал ветку NewB.
5. Поработал в ветке NewB. И вдруг сообразил, что важные настройки лежали в старой версии NewB.

**Вопрос:** можно ли восстановить старую NewB? Проблема в том, что я в ней поработал, но коммитов и индексаций не делал. Просто, когда переходил в мастер, переходил с **-f.**

Comment: если ничего не коммитилось и не "индексировалось", то по сути Ваша ветка это просто синоним какого то коммита в мастере. А значит, ничего не восстановить.

Comment: Если коммитов не делали, то что хотите восстановить? Изменения в локальной копии, которые вы отменили?

Comment: Я хочу восстановить то что было, на момент git checkout master

Comment: Если вы коммитили, то можно попробовать найти нужный коммит где-нибудь на просторах git reflog. Если не коммитили - ну, тогда гит здесь уже ни при чём, соболезнуем

Comment: 

Comment: поищите в мусорке : `git log --all --full-history --graph` нить `stash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ветку восстановить можно, только в этой ситуации, к сожалению, восстановить изменения это не поможет.

Ветка это указатель на комит. Когда создаете ветку, то она изначально указывает на тот комит, от которого ее породили.

Так как вы новых комитов не создавали, а только меняли локальную копию, то изменения нигде не сохранились, и восстановление ветки не поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, уже понял. 

Comment: @AndrewKachalin поэтому коммитить надо всё. Любую глупость (можно в отдельные ветки). Удалить потом ненужные ветки и коммиты проще, чем восстанавливать несохранённый код.